# Messages are dropping because too many are queued in AlertManager

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have single instance cluster for AlertManager and I see warning in AlertManager container `level=warn ts=2021-11-03T08:50:44.528Z caller=delegate.go:272 component=cluster msg="dropping messages because too many are queued" current=4125 limit=4096`

**Alert Manager Version information:**

```
Version Information
Branch: HEAD
BuildDate: 20190708-14:31:49
BuildUser: root@868685ed3ed0
GoVersion: go1.12.6
Revision: 1ace0f76b7101cccc149d7298022df36039858ca
Version: 0.18.0
```

**AlertManager metrics**

```
# HELP alertmanager_cluster_members Number indicating current number of members in cluster.
# TYPE alertmanager_cluster_members gauge
alertmanager_cluster_members 1
# HELP alertmanager_cluster_messages_pruned_total Total number of cluster messages pruned.
# TYPE alertmanager_cluster_messages_pruned_total counter
alertmanager_cluster_messages_pruned_total 23020
# HELP alertmanager_cluster_messages_queued Number of cluster messages which are queued.
# TYPE alertmanager_cluster_messages_queued gauge
alertmanager_cluster_messages_queued 4125
```

- How do we see those queued messages in AlertManager?
- Do we lose alerts when messages are dropped because of too many
  queued ?
- Why are messages queued even though there is logic to prune messages
  on regular interval i.e 15 minutes ?
- Do we lose alerts when AlertManager pruned messages on regular interval?

I am new to alerting. Could you please answer for the above questions?

Comment: Do you get any errors with send the notifications as well ? or just the large queue?

Comment: No. I get this warning "level=warn ts=2021-11-03T08:50:44.528Z caller=delegate.go:272 component=cluster msg="dropping messages because too many are queued" current=4125 limit=4096" in AlertManager. This causes to alerts are not reaching to configured notification channel e.g slack, webhook.